# vector as linear combination of other vectors with one more perpendicular vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, svd

I am reading about Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) from book [SVD CSTheory Infoage.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/book-chapter-4.pdf)

At page 6, the chapter says:

A matrix $A$ can be described fully by how it transforms the vectors $v_i$. Every vector $v$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1, v_2,  ... v_r$ and **a vector perpendicular to all the $v_i$.**
Now, $A * v$ is the same linear combination of $A * v_1, A * v_2, .... A *v_r$ as $v$ is of $v_1, v_2,  ... v_r$
So the $A * v_1, A * v_2, .... A *v_r$ form a fundamental set of vectors associated with A.

Here $v_j$'s are right singular-vectors.

I could not understand why is a more vector perpendicular to the $v_i$ is required ?

Note: Question is related to the bold part of the above text.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E=span(v_1,\cdots,v_r)$ and $F$ be its orthogonal. Then $\mathbb{R}^d= E\oplus F$. If $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$, then $v=\sum_i a_iv_i+w$ where $w\in F$. Since $Aw=0$, $Av=\sum_i a_iAv_i$ and $im(A)=span(Av_1,\cdots, Av_r)$ and $r=rank(A)$.

Comment: can you give any link that supports : $v=\sum_i a_iv_i+w$  i thought vector v requires only $v=\sum_i a_iv_i$

Comment: and why is $Aw = 0$ ? can A only be the space of E ?

Comment: 1. We seek $im(A)$; then we consider $v$  in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and not in $E$.  2. $A$ is injective on $E$ and is $0$ on $F$ (cf; page 4, line(-3)).